# Can a superclass inherit methods from its sub class?

Tags: c++, inheritance

I know that subclasses can inherit methods from the super class, but can a super class do the same for its sub class? For example:

```
Alpha *a = new Alpha ();
Beta *b = new Beta ();
Gamma *g = new Gamma ();
g = b;
```

On the fourth statement, I am creating a Gamma object to be a Beta object, but Gamma is the super class and beta is the sub class. So either g gets a pointer to b or this code will not compile and I do not quite understand which answer is correct. If someone could please clarify that would be great.

Comment: The code should not compile.

Comment: *"On the fourth statement, I am creating a Gamma object"*. The only thing the fourth statement is creating is a memory leak.

Comment: Can you explain more clearly what the inheritance structure of `Alpha`, `Beta`, and `Gamma` is? (Just the `class` lines for each one should suffice.)

Comment: Gamma is the super class, and Beta and Alpha are the sub classes. It was just a question that I was asked and this was all the information I was given. I assumed since the super class had no information from the sub classes that it should not be able to, so I was just clarifying.

Comment: Could virtual functions be what you want?

Comment: Umm I doubt it, hes never talked about virtual classes before, this is the first time im hearing of it actually.

Answer (score 2):

It can't *inherit* them technically, but it can *use* them if you use the [Curiously Recurring Template Pattern (CRTP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern).

```
template<class SubClass>
class SuperClass
{
    void DoSomething()
    {
        static_cast<SubClass *>(this)->Foo();
    }
};

class SubClass: public SuperClass<SubClass>
{
    void Foo();
};
```

Comment: Indeed, this is a way to access your function, but you definitely should review your design if you're explicitly calling a function from your templated subclass....

Answer (score 1):

No, superclass cannot inherit methods from its subclass because in general a superclass **should not** have any knowledge of what derive from it.

Comment: what if you have 2 classes which inherit from each-other?  INFINITE POLYMORPHISM!!!

Comment: @SamIam (off-topic) that reminds me of the times when mages sheep each other at the same time in WoW; *baaaah~* ;)